# R - apply over increasing submatrices, instead of individual rows/cols

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

So I've been pondering how to do this without a for loop and I couldn't come up with a good answer. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
sampleData <- matrix(rnorm(25,0,1),5,5)
meanVec <- vector(length=length(sampleData[,1]))

for(i in 1:length(sampleData[,1])){
        subMat <- sampleData[1:i,]
        ifelse( i == 1 , sumVec <- sum(subMat) ,sumVec <- apply(subMat,2,sum) )
        meanVec[i] <- mean(sumVec)
    }
meanVec
```

The actual matrix I want to do this to is reasonably large, and to be honest, for this application it won't make a huge difference in speed, but it's a question I think should be answered:

How can I get rid of that for loop and replace with some *ply call?

Edit: In the example given, I generate sample data, and define a vector equal to the number of rows in the vector.

The for loop does the following steps:

1) takes a submatrix, from row 1 to row i

2) if i is 1, it just sums up the values in that vector

3) if i is not 1, it gets the sum of each row, then gets the mean of the sum and stores that in position i of the vector meanVec.

Finally, it prints out the mean of that sum.

Comment: Can you please explain in your question what that code is doing?

Comment: `length(subMat) <= length(sampleData[1,])` is always FALSE for i>1

Comment: Sorry, I cleared up the code a little and added an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you describe:

```
cumsum(rowSums(sampleData))/seq_len(nrow(sampleData))
```

However, your code doesn't do the same.

Comment: If you used `apply(subMat, 1, sum)` (which calculates row sums) in your code it would be the same.